# how i can scrape google link when make a request for get link its say please wait after 3 second link generate and its cant scrape

Tags: python, web-scraping

http://linkblend.icu/nAK5f
 this is link

this is code

```
url='http://linkblend.icu/nAK5f'
req=requests.get(url).text
soup=BeautifulSoup(req,'html.parser')
data=soup.findAll('a')
print(data)
```

this is result

```
[<a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Link Blend</a>, <a href="/advertising-rates">Advertising</a>, <a href="/payout-rates">Payout Rates</a>, <a class="btn btn-success btn-lg get-link disabled" href="javascript: void(0)">
            Please wait...        </a>, <a href="/pages/privacy">Privacy Policy</a>, <a href="/pages/terms">Terms of Use</a>, <a href="https://www.facebook.com/#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>, <a href="https://twitter.com/#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>, <a href="https://plus.google.com/#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>]
```

Comment: please can you tell me where is this question also mention.?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to continue using BeautifulSoup to parse the html source, with the help of Selenium you use the following

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver as wd

""" Initiate the firefox driver """
driver = wd.Firefox()

""" Navigate to desired url """
driver.get('site.com')

""" retrieve source """
html = driver.page_source

""" Parse via BeautifulSoup """
soup = bs(html)

""" Locate tag """
data=soup.findAll('a')
print(data)

""" Close down browser """
driver.close()
```

Comment: ```driver=wd.Firefox()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    driver=wd.Firefox()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 163, in __init__
    log_path=service_log_path)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\service.py", line 44, in __init__
    log_file = open(log_path, "a+") if log_path is not None and log_path != "" else None
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'geckodriver.log' ```

Comment: i got this error  permission denied: ' geckodriver.log '

Comment: You might need an update: pip install --upgrade selenium

Comment: yeah sir i already upgrade still not working

Comment: Be sure to have Firefox installed on your system and install the geckodriver from: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.24.0

Comment: and save it in a folder of your choosing, as long as you have read and write access to it. Reference the file by using wd.Firefox(executable_path="/usr/local/bin/geckodriver") hope that helps :)